# $(\mathbb{N},\mathscr{B})$ measurable space with lebesgue measure: integral question

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Part of a HW question reads:

> Let $X=\mathbb{N}$ and let $\mathscr{F}=\mathscr{B}$ (borel sets), and let $\mu$ be the Lebesgue measure on the borel sets. If $f_n=\chi_{[0,n]}$, then the sequence converges to $f=\chi_{[0,\infty]}$. Although the functions are bounded by $1$ and the integrals of each of the $f_n$ are all finite, we have $\int f d\mu = + \infty$.

I am so confused, how is it that $\int f d\mu = + \infty$?

Our set is $\mathbb N$. Our measurable sets are the borel sets (so singleton sets belonging to $\mathbb{N}$, which are closed, unions and intersections of these singleton sets belonging to $\mathbb{N}$ would be examples of measurable sets). But we have the Lebesgue measure as the measure of our measurable space $(\mathbb{N},\mathscr{B})$ and I thought this measure assigns $0$ to countable sets. So our space should have measure $0$. How is it that $\int f d\mu = + \infty$?

There is definitely something I haven't learned or understood correctly.

Comment: It seems like we should have $X=\mathbb R$. Perhaps there is an error in the question?

Comment: @Math1000 Apparently there was no typo. You are supposed to understand the Lebesgue measure in that measurable space as the counting measure. To me honestly that doesn't make much sense. But maybe it is just convention.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. Perhaps you're supposed to interpret "Borel sets" as "Borel sets on $\mathbb N$"? But even this doesn't make much sense, as when a set is countably infinite then one can simply take the power set as a $\sigma$-algebra and define a measure that way.

Comment: I think with "borel sets" it is implied (?) "borel sets on $N $" since $X=N$ and the sigma algebra has to be a collection of subsets of our set $X$. I have just been thinking about this too much, but maybe the above is not true. What I find confusing is the "Lebesgue measure on $N$," usually you think of the Lebesgue Measure on $R^d$.

Comment: The question makes sense if we interpret $\mu$ as counting measure, and does not if we interpret it as Lebesgue measure. So I would say that the question is written poorly.